# yii imagemagick php5.4 to php7

Tags: php, yii, imagemagick

We've been using imagemagick in Yii for a couple of years to allow people to "decorate" a balloon online. Running on php5.4 this has always worked really well. Here's an example of one of the "balloons"
[balloon with working decorator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEeOp.png)
We recently upgraded the website to run on php7 for a variety of reasons. Sadly this has meant imagemagick isn't working the way it used to. See this link for an example:
[balloon without working decorator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZhWo.png)
I wont say it's broken because I don't believe it is. I think we need to tweak/update the code. The problem is even the guy who implemented this for us can't work it out. This is the problem in his words

> First command extracts the non-transparent part of the image and the second colours it. According to my tests, the first command (-alpha extract) works perfectly, however the latter (-background COLOUR -alpha shape) does colour the whole image, not just the extracted part.

Here's the code we're trying to use (and has successfully worked on php5.4 for over two years):

```
  public function color($params) {

    if (isset($params['pattern'])) {

        $error = exec(escapeshellcmd($this->dir . 'convert' . $this->ext) . ' ' . $this->cmd_image . ' -alpha extract ' . $this->cmd_image);

        $error .= exec(escapeshellcmd($this->dir . 'convert' . $this->ext) . ' ' . $this->cmd_image . ' tile:' . $params['pattern'] . ' \ -compose Multiply  -composite ' . $this->cmd_image);

        $error .= exec(escapeshellcmd($this->dir . 'convert' . $this->ext) . ' ' . $this->cmd_image . ' -background \'' . $params['color_code'] . '\' -alpha shape ' . $this->cmd_image);



        if (!$error) {

            return TRUE;
        } else {

            return FALSE;
        }
    } else {

        $error = exec(escapeshellcmd($this->dir . 'convert' . $this->ext) . ' ' . $this->cmd_image . ' -alpha extract ' . $this->cmd_image);


        $error .= exec(escapeshellcmd($this->dir . 'convert' . $this->ext) . ' ' . $this->cmd_image . ' -background \'' . $params['color_code'] . '\' -alpha shape ' . $this->cmd_image);


        if (!$error) {

            return TRUE;
        } else {

            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Any and all suggestions as to what we're doing wrong in php7 gratefully received!

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you got a suitable starting image for me to play with please?

Comment: Yeah, here you go http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4ndh.png

Comment: Does this get you what you want at the command line? `convert http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4ndh.png \( +clone -fill red -colorize 100% \) +swap -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png`

Comment: We'll soon find out. Thanks :)

Comment: Or, more simply without any special quoting, for a quick test... `convert -size 140x140 xc:red http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4ndh.png -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png`

Comment: Yes it did, thanks Mark. The whole "decorator" thing we have also can apply a couple of patterns and also image uploading. If you fancy taking a look at the whole shebang the boss is willing to part with a few quid to fix it.

Comment: In fact, this should also work and be even easier... `convert http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4ndh.png -fill yellow -colorize 100% result.png`

Comment: Presumably we could swap "yellow" to a colour chosen by the user? Let me know if you fancy a look at the whole decorator. Thanks again for your help.